Default Mac OS 8 default desktop color
I'm trying to find the CMYK or RGB equivalent for the standard Mac OS 8 default desktop color. Appreciate any assistance. Thank you!

The desktop color in the emulator at https://infinitemac.org/1998/Mac%20OS%208.1 seems to be #B3B3DA:


Be careful about gamma, calibration, etc.  From the ppat resource in the Desktop Pictures control panel, "French Blue accent light" is #9999cc. But #9999cc on macos/windows/x-windows/wayland with a 2024 LCD monitor probably won't match #9999cc on a 90s mac with a 90s Sony trinitron.

Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

@KelvinSherlock's comment says he extracted the color as #9999cc. This would be under the old Apple RGB gamut. Apple's gamma of 1.8, and the primaries differ from the modern sRGB baseline.
Converting #9999cc with the Apple RGB profile to sRGB perceptually yields #B9B9D5.

